# Laravel assert multiple recipients of email during PHPUnit test

Tags: php, laravel, email, phpunit

I want to test that an email has been sent to a number of addresses during a PHPUnit test. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking) does indicate that a `hasTo()` function exists within the `Mail` object:

```
// Assert a message was sent to the given users...
Mail::assertSent(OrderShipped::class, function ($mail) use ($user) {
    return $mail->hasTo($user->email) &&
                   $mail->hasCc('...') &&
                   $mail->hasBcc('...');
});
```

It does not make clear that it is possible to assert that multiple address have been sent the mail. The `hasTo` function accepts the following structure as expected assertions:

```
[
    [
        'email' => 'johnny@appleseed.com',
        'name' => 'Johnny Appleseed'
    ],
    [
        'email' => 'jane@appleseed.com',
        'name' => 'Jane Appleseed'
    ],
]
```

As the name key is optional, the simplest way to test that specific users have received an email would look something like this:

```
Mail::fake();

$admins = User::where('administrator', true)->get()->map(function ($admin) {
    return ['email' => $admin->email];
})->toArray();

Mail::assertSent(MyMailable::class, function ($mail) use ($admins) {
    return $mail->hasTo($admins);
});
```

If you have used the default Laravel User model, or your user model has both `name` and `email` properties, you can pass your users in as a collection

```
Mail::fake();

$admins = User::where('administrator', true)->get();

Mail::assertSent(MyMailable::class, function ($mail) use ($admins) {
    return $mail->hasTo($admins);
});
```

Comment: Awesome, great reply.